# Palantir Foundry Fusion access using API

Tags: palantir-foundry

I want to extract all the data from my Palantir foundry fusion sheet using API and paste it in excel locally? How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

after syncing your fusion sheet to a dataset you can dl it via phonograph2 APIs.
there are two services for that:

1. Table Search Service (I heard it is going to deprecate soon)
2. Object Search Service

I recommend you to use the 2nd one for the mentioned reason.
to hit phonograph API you need to understand how it is deployed on your org.
and most probably you need a reverse proxy to bypass CROS policy.

to understand how to write your query you should read the very bad written documentation of Palantir/Foundry/APIs/Phonograph2.
example below is a nodejs matchAll query generated by postman, which worked for me.

Good luck with finding the right params to pass :D

```
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
  myHeaders.append("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
  myHeaders.append("Accept-Language", "en-US, en;q=0.9");
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
// also set orgin, refere, authorization (your token) and authority to make it work
// here I dropped them to avoid any security issue 

var raw = "{\r\n    \"objectTypes\": [\r\n        \"your-object-id\"\r\n        ],\r\n    \"filter\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"matchAll\",\r\n        \"matchAll\": {}\r\n    }\r\n}";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://your-url.whatever/phonograph2/api/objects/search/objects", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any API to extract data out of Fusion. I don't know how big your fusions are, but if you intend to paste it into your excel locally you can do it with your clipboard already:

1 - Select the rows on fusion and CTRL + C (mac: CMD + C)
[image]

2 - Select the rows on excel that you want to past and CTRL + V (mac: CMD + V)

[image]

Comment: i want to automate this cutting data from Fusion and pasting in excel. Thats why i am looking for API or any other automation tool which does this job for me.So will appreciate if you suggest any tool (Selenium can not) or a way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you sync the Fusion sheet to a dataset and download the dataset via API?

Comment: thats is exactly my question! How can i download the data using API (this part i dont know) once i sync the dataset

Comment: There are other answers here on SO that describe that.